# Краткое описание - это презентационная речь в лифте о метке

Tags: дефект, локализация, привилегии

Мне кажется, что эта фраза какая-то странная.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user

> Краткое описание - это презентационная речь в лифте о метке.

Comment: Оригинал: `The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.`

Comment: Видимо, жаргон менеджеров: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Презентация_для_лифта

Comment: «elevator pitch» — это распространенная на Западе фраза. Мы можем придумать свою. Пожалуйста, предлагайте ваши варианты!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, выдержка, отрывок, вступление

Comment: Ага, краткое описание) Или может удалить предложение?

Comment: Элеватор питч больше популярен в бизнесе и стартапах. У нас, в принципе, в рамках геймдева эта фраза набирает обороты. Но в среднем для IT сферы - это не так распространено. Я бы перевёл в нашем контексте как "Краткое описание - лаконичная фраза, ёмко описывающая метку".

Comment: Или можно вот: `инструкция по применению метки`

Comment: Инструкция - это совсем другое, вот не надо

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, фразу можно заменить на следующую:

> Краткое описание — это вводная по метке, выраженная одним-двумя короткими предложениями.

Comment: Нужно уточнить, что такое _вводная_, тогда будет хорошо.

Comment: Да всё ж [понятно](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F) :) Добавить слово «информация» и готово.